# Read object from Ajax Call Results

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, javascript-objects

I have an AJAX, calling a PHP file and getting this as result:
(*****These are the results from trackAndTrace of a courier)

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["TrackAndTraceResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (5) {
    ["Result"]=>
    int(0)
    ["Checkpoints"]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
      ["Checkpoint"]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(63) "Αναχώρηση από σημείο εξυπηρέτησης"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-03T17:08:11"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(47) "TOWN 1"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#8 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(67) "Αναχώρηση από κέντρο διαμετακόμισης"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-03T19:37:12"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(22) "TOWN 2"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(7) "4066XXX"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(7) "2288XXX"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(67) "Αναχώρηση από κέντρο διαμετακόμισης"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-04T01:10:13"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(19) "TOWN 3"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(7) "3959XXX"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(7) "224XXX"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(53) "Άφιξη σε σημείο εξυπηρέτησης"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-04T07:56:58"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(14) "TOWN 4"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(35) "Παράδοση αποστολής"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-04T15:49:01"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(14) "TOWN 5"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(7) "3955XXX"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(7) "2176XXX"
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#12 (5) {
          ["Status"]=>
          string(58) "Καταχώρηση στοιχείων παράδοσης"
          ["StatusDate"]=>
          string(19) "2020-06-04T17:08:24"
          ["Shop"]=>
          string(14) "TOWN 6"
          ["Latitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["Longitude"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
    }
    ["Status"]=>
    string(20) "DELIVERED AT"
    ["DeliveryDate"]=>
    string(19) "2020-06-04T15:49:00"
    ["Consignee"]=>
    string(40) "PERSON - USER"
  }
}
```

How could I get all these arrays / objects results?

I tried many things like:

```
const res = returnData;
console.log(res.TrackAndTraceResult);
console.log(res["TrackAndTraceResult"]);
console.log(res.TrackAndTraceResult.Checkpoints.Checkpoint);
```

but nothing works. Could someone explain me and suggest me a way to get all these fields results?

thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a var_dump from PHP, are you asking how to convert a PHP object to JS readable mode before responding, or do you want (have to) to parse that response with JS?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time! this is the response I got from Ajax.. How could I proceed with that result? I want to parse it somehow and echo/display them in.

I have something like that for now:
$("#results").html(...);
I would like to beautify it, in HTML

Comment: It would be easiest to fix the data at the server. If you can't affect to the result, you need to create a parser in JS.

Comment: This is a request from another server.. I do not have access to it..Thus, how could I parse this result? How could I get the "Checkpoint[0]..checkpoint[1]" etc

Comment: Like I said, you need to create a parser. Tokenize the result text and translate the tokens to corresponding JS data structure. Maybe it's worth of searching for existing parser(s), creating a reliable parser for this is not a trivial task. If you can't find any, you should try to implement your own, if you'll get stuck, then ask a question.

Comment: I spoke with the man who has the server and build the API and told me that the respond should be an XML.. Should I add any headers or something, thus I get the appropriate respond?